# Exim - password disclosure by world-readable exim.conf - is that necessary?

Tags: linux, security, exim

I saw `/etc/exim.conf` is world-readable.  The issue with this is to configure Exim to use an SMTP service like Sendgrid to route all outgoing email, you put your username and password into that file, which would then allow unprivileged users on the server to obtain it.

Is there any reason why this file can't be made only readable by root?  I wonder why it wouldn't default to that given the possibility of it containing sensitive information.  Does anyone know?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57523 Jun 19 23:16 /etc/exim.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally passwords would go into a password file and be read as need by the transport that needs it.  The example configuration should contain auth examples for both server and client connections.  It is possible to configure multiple authentication methods for server authentication and/or client authentication.

Exim uses two passwords files by default: `/etc/exim/passwd` for users connecting to exim, and `/etc/exim/passwd.client` when exim is connecting to a remote server.

Comment: So would I just make that password file readable by the user the exim daemon runs as? I'm not very experienced with exim, but it appears my password goes in an authenticator block - is that different than a transport?  Any thoughts on poige's solution of just giving the exim user group read access to the conf file and removing world read? Thanks

Comment: @sa289 Your password is used in an authenticator block, but it should not be defined there.  It should be in one of the password files: `/etc/exim/passwd` or `/etc/exim/passwd.client`.  The password files should be appropriately secured.  Ubuntu/Debian leaves the generated configuration file with 644 access, which agrees with my understanding that it may need to be run using almost anyone's privileges.

Comment: Thanks.  So exim isn't just run as a daemon / service then, but rather individual users may run it themselves?  Any idea if that is typical or just an uncommon use case?  I tried searching for more on this but searches keep bringing up unrelated results =(.

Comment: @sa289 Users are less likely to invoke exim than programs they use.  One well defined method of delivering email is to invoke sendmail (exim is symlinked) and use it to start the message on its way.  Programs like mail and mailx typically use the sendmail interface to deliver mail.

Comment: Okay, so then in the setup you're suggesting, would users potentially launch exim (directly or indirectly), but then it would talk to the exim service which would only be what's able to read the exim passwd files? Thx

Comment: @sa289 Yes, however root always has access.  The only time exim should need passwords is when it is running as the user it is programmed to use when processing message for or from its queue.

Answer (score 2):

Good point. Good for you that you think about security of configs in particular. The answer is it depends (as usual). For e. g., if you have exim running in its own OpenVZ/LXC/Docker/KVM/XEN/PhysicalServer ergh... let's call it "scope", you can bother not, probably, as except `root` there wouldn't be anyone who could peek into this config.

At contrary, if the "scope" is shared with different not-that-trusted users (unlikely, if you're pro-secure admin), file permissions can be considered important, no doubts.

As for `exim`, you should check out its manuals and find whether it's being used by any non-privileged user, say, often there's `exim` user/group used to run `exim` daemon. If by logic of `exim` service operations the config file in question should be readable to `exim` user, you could think that user `exim` can be the owner of the config. But in fact, this is a security breach, cause had `exim` service running under `exim` user compromised, an attacker can change the config.

The solution I can propose is using group-access for that purpose. Make sure `exim` user is a member of some group you choose to have READ-access to the config file, set group access permission to "read-only" and, in theory, you can safely remove any access for "others".

Comment: This is a better answer. Thanks.